# How to replace sensenet logo?

Tags: sensenet

I have to make some changes on the ui. Now I try to replace the built-in sensenet logo, but I am stucked. I tried to change `/Root/Global/images/sensenetlogo.png` but there is no option to replace it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo is defined in a css file (/Root/Skins/sensenet/styles/skin.css)

Search for this part:

```
.sn-layout-inter-index .sn-slogen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 13px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url(/Root/Global/images/sensenetlogo.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and change the background-image url. This will will replace the logo on the homepage.

Replacing the logo on other subpages change the logo url the same way at

```
.sn-layout-intra .sn-layout-head .sn-logo, .sn-layout-inter .sn-layout-head .sn-logo, .sn-layout1 .sn-layout-head .sn-logo {
...
}
```

If you installed sensenet from source make sure that you changed the .css file both in the file system and through sensenet's admin surface (Content Explorer).

Comment: i added  logo image in /Root/Global/images/ourlogo.PNG and replaced code with same url:                                                                                            .sn-layout-inter-index .sn-slogen {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url(/Root/Global/images/ourlogo.PNG) 20px 50% no-repeat;
    padding-left: 170px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 400px;
}                                          but its not replacing default logo ;(

Comment: I done all changes but still it showing default logo. ( i don't deleted default logo)

Comment: Did you change the skin of your site? Have you made a custom skin?

Comment: nope i am using default skin with Sense/Net  version 6.5.4.9243

Comment: Can you share your site's url?

Comment: site is locally hosted. :(

Comment: Where did you change the css? In the Content Explorer (admin surface) or in the file system?

Comment: How did you install sensenet, from source or with the webpi package?

Comment: i installed using source

Comment: Try to change the skin.css file not only on sensenet's admin surface but also in your file system (on your local machine)

Comment: I've added info to my answer that it must be checked in the file system and in the content explorer too. If it was helpful pls approve my answer. Thanks! :)